# Modifying a touch controlled lamp

Tags: lamp

My touch lamp tipped over while it was on, the bulb went out.

Ever since my touch lamp will just stay ON when it's plugged in, the touch feature no longer works.

I know I can replace the touch lighting control, but I was thinking instead of doing that, is it possible to add just a inline switch?

Without removing the touch lighting control and just adding a switch will the lamp still work?

Comment: Did you replace the bulb with something other than the kind that was in it ?

Comment: Yes I did. The light will remain on when plugged in. I read that if the light bulb sparked out it will damage the touch lighting control, so that's what happen here. So I was thinking to prevent that from happening again, can a switch be added to lamp without any problems.

Comment: @oliveoil10 **"Yes i did"** , I was asking because the new bulb may not be compatible with the touch function. Only relevant if you want it to function as intended but not if you want to put an inline switch in the cord.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to ad a switched cord like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006Y6O4J2)

It has a long cord so you can position it where it is convenient for you. 
You plug the plug end of the cord into the wall and the lamp plug into the plug end and run cord with the switch to the area of your choosing.

The one liked to is dimmable so you can get a dimmable bulb or you can get a non dimmable one as well. I have seen them in the extension cord area of The blue big box home improvement store. I  have two.

There is also [this switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0033PSGD2) that can be added to your lamps existing cord. This requires you to cut one leads  of the cord,( *Make sure to cut the hot lead: the one that is not ribbed*.) Strip the insulation back and connect it to two screws inside the switch.

**Of coarse you would do this with lamp not plugged into the wall.**

Comment: Make sure to cut the hot lead: the one that is not ribbed. Neutral should not be interrupted (or to be more precise, hot *should* be interrupted; but regardless you should always unplug this type of switch when changing bulb, because it is usually impossible to tell if the switch is on or off.)

Comment: that is what I'm thinking of doing, adding that switch. But will it be a problem if I don't remove the touch control. the cord for the lamp is clear  and is smooth on both wires, but one side has writing on it.

Comment: Thanks Harper, i added your info to my answer.  Oliveoil10, if you plug and unplug you lamp several times in a row and it always comes on when you plug it in then it should be fine.